# Run button in VS code compiles C++ code, but runs it in Debug Console instead of integrated Terminal

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, debugging, terminal, console

I use VS code on Mac OS for programming with C++. Pressing the run triangle button successfully compiles the code and it starts running in the Debug Console automatically. I can't use the Debug Console, because it doesn't accept keyboard entries in run-time for some reason. Is it possible to automatically run the code in the integrated Terminal instead, when pressing the run button?
Do I need to configure the launch.json?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> Do I need to configure the launch.json?

Yes. There's an attribute `console` that can be set to `integratedTerminal`.

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Some Name",
            // ...
            "console": "integratedTerminal"
        }
    ]
}
```

Depending on the extension you are using, you may need to create `.vscode/launch.json' manually. Sooner or later you may need a custom launch file anyway (e.g. when passing arguments).

Comment: Thanks. The "console" attribute didn't work for me. However I managed to have an external terminal opened via "externalConsole": true

Answer (score 0):

One workaround is to add the following attribute to the launch.json:

```
"externalConsole": true
```

It doesn't solve the problem completely but at least one can interact with the keyboard at runtime; also, you don't have to start the program via typing.